# Group by and sum operation on a String array

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a `String[]` `dataValues` as below:

```
ONE:9
TWO:23
THREE:14
FOUR:132
ONE:255
TWO:727
FIVE:3
THREE:196
FOUR:1843
ONE:330
TWO:336
THREE:190
FOUR:3664
```

I want to total the values of `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`, `FOUR`, `FIVE`.

So I created a `HashMap` for the same:

```
Map<String, Integer> totals = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for(String dataValue : dataValues){
    String[] keyVal = dataValue.split(":");
      totals.put(keyVal[0], totals.get(keyVal[0]).intValue() + Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]));                            
}
```

But above code will **obviously throw** below exception if the key is not already existing in the map:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What is the best way to get the totals in my usecase above?

Comment: Check for null, put current number if null, sum if not null.

Comment: `totals.get(keyVal[0])` is null because you dint put any value in map of `keyVal[0]` yet

Comment: @downVoter: As I mentioned in the question (bold now), I know that the null pointer exception gets thrown as the key is not yet existing and I can solve it be entering a null check. My question (see the last line in my post) is -- what is the best way to get the totals in my usecase. Using a map with a null check as above is one of the way. But is it the best way ?

Comment: @downVoter: Downvoting without understanding op's perspective is sometimes demotivating.

Comment: @Jens: Just see the number of ways the problem was solved in the answers below. And there are new concepts from Java 8 introduced which helps everyone learn and I think that is the primary purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: "*My question (see the last line in my post) is -- what is the best way to get the totals in my usecase*" I suspect that is precisely why you get down-voted. Questions about "*best way to do something*" are very often opinion based or too broad and such questions may be considered as off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Pshemo: Do you mean to say we should not ask questions about "best way" or "most optimal way" or "easiest way" to achieve something in a programming language on stackoverflow ?

Comment: I am not saying that everyone here thinks so (you also got few up-votes, didn't you?), but we as community have right to cast our votes as we believe is right, so don't treat downvotes as something personal but as sign that not all liked this question.

Comment: @Pshemo: I agree with you entirely. I am not taking the downvote as personal. But downvoting for - null pointer exception when my question clearly shows that I do understand the reason behind null pointer exception and way to solve it - is what I find not a valid reason to downvote. :) Isn't it?

Comment: *"But downvoting for - null pointer exception"* How do you know that this was the reason for the downvotes?

Comment: @Jens This question isn't about *why NPE is thrown* but how to avoid it with clean code so this is not actually a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Java 8 instead of `map.get` you can use `map.getOrDefault` which in case of lack of data will return default data defined by you like

```
totals.getOrDefault(keyVal[0], 0).intValue()
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need `getOrDefault`. `totals.merge(keyVal[0], Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]), Integer::sum);` is sufficient here.

Comment: @AlexisC. Very nice code. Why isn't this snippet part of your answer? I know you described this approach but including this code would also be very helpful to see what you mean.

Comment: @Pshemo I've added an explanation then :)

Comment: @AlexisC. Too bad I can't upvote it more than once :)

Comment: @Trobbins Yes, it is clean, readable, short approach. I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Trobbins Except that you compute the hashcode twice. If it's a `TreeMap` it's worse because you'll perform 2 lookups in the tree (and a tree has `logN` access). That's why I stored the result of  `get` in my pre-java 8 answer.

Comment: @AlexisC. Fantastic, I'm glad I asked for improvement. Thanks very much.

Comment: I wonder if JIT would optimize this code to avoid this hash recalculation by moving `map.get(key)` outside of `map.put` (if it knows that map is used only in one thread).

Comment: @Pshemo Good question! I think one way would be to benchmark this two snippets. If you have very close results then I think we can deduce that JIT has effectively optimized this calls. Actually I don't know if there is a way to grab the bytecode at a time t to see what JIT has optimized?

Comment: @Trobbins: Infact since I am on Java 6, I used your solution. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just get the value for the given key and checks if its not null:

```
for(String dataValue : dataValues){
    String[] keyVal = dataValue.split(":");
    Integer i = totals.get(keyVal[0]);
    if(i == null) {
        totals.put(keyVal[0], Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]));
    } else {
        totals.put(keyVal[0], i + Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]));
    }
 }
```

---

> What is the best way to get the totals in my usecase above?

With Java 8 you can use the merge function

```
for(String dataValue : dataValues){
    String[] keyVal = dataValue.split(":");
    totals.merge(keyVal[0], Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]), Integer::sum);
}
```

What this function does? Let's cite the doc:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is
>   associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.
>   Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given
>   remapping function, or removes if the result is null

So as you get it, if there is no value associated with the key, you just map it with the int value of `keyVal[1]`. If there is already one, you need to provide a function to decide what you will do with both values (the one that is already mapped and the one that you want to map).

In your case you want to sum them, so this function looks like `(a, b) -> a + b`, which can be replaced by the method reference `Integer.sum` because it's a function that takes two int and returns an int, so a valid candidate (and that have the semantic you need of course).

---

But wait, we can actually do better! This is where the Stream API and the collectors class come handy.

Get a `Stream<String>` from the file, split each line into an array, group each array by its first element (the key), map its second element (the values) to integer and sum them:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

...

Map<String, Integer> map = Files.lines(Paths.get("file"))
    .map(s -> s.split(":"))
    .collect(groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], summingInt(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1])));
```

and another way would be to use the `toMap` collector.

```
.collect(toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1]), Integer::sum));
```

From the same `Stream<String[]>`, you collect the results in a `Map<String, Integer>` from which the key is `arr[0]`, the values are the int values hold by `arr[1]`. If you have the same keys you merge the values by summing them.

Both give the same result, I like the first one because with the name of the collector it makes the intent clear that you are grouping elements but it's up to you to choose.

Maybe a bit difficult to understand it at first, but it's very powerful once you grab the concept of these (downstream) collectors.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: It did help. Thanks for introducing a new feature.

Comment: Another option, using `groupingBy()` without `mapping()`: .collect(groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], summingInt(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))))

Comment: @AndersonVieira Ha yes, don't know how I missed that, thanks! Definitely more clear. Updating :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an elegant (edit: pre Java 8) solution :

```
Integer storedVal = hashMap.get(str);  

String str = keyVal[0];
int num = Integer.parseInt(keyVal[1]);

hashMap.put(str, storedVal == null ? num : storedVal + num);
```

Check to see that the key exists. If it does not, create it with your held int.

If the key does exist, retrieve the value and do math, storing the sum.

This works because if a key already exists, a 'put' will override the value.